# Рассчитать точный размер полезного места в Physical Volume на LVM2 при расширении раздела

Tags: linux, lvm

**Задача:** рассчитать точный размер полезного места на PV-томе исходя из размера раздела, на котором PV располагается.

**Контекст:**
Есть PV-раздел, для него можно сделать `pvs --unit B -o pv_name,pv_size` и узнать точный размер PV в байтах на данный момент.
При этом PV занимает не весь объём нижележащего раздела/диска.
Есть размер нижележащего раздела/диска в байтах.

Нужно рассчитать полезный объём PV после того как он будет расширен на весь нижележащий диск командой pvresize, но без собственно расширения (т.е. расширить и посмотреть не подходит - надо посчитать заранее).

Comment: вызов pvresize с опциями `-t` (`--test`) и `-v` (`--verbose`) не подходит?

Comment: опцию -t уже нашел, но задача осталась для несколько другого контекста: будет создан новый раздел и на нем PV. Нужно узнать полезный размер нового PV без создания раздела и без создания PV, т.е. чисто рассчетным методом.

Comment: вносите изменения в вопрос, либо (лучше) удаляйте текущий (право на удаление есть только у вас и у модераторов) и задавайте новый.

Comment: Оформите ответ ответом - я его отмечу, т.к. задачу он решает и создам новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно `man pvresize`, у этой программы есть опция `-t` (`--test`).

при запуске с этой опцией (и с опцией `-v` (`--verbose`)) реальные изменения произведены не будут, но в выводе будет присутствовать вся (обычная) информация об изменении размера физического тома.